# cMake to compile C source files with g++ compiler

Tags: c, cmake, g++

I have been asked to compile C Source codes with g++ compiler in cMake environment.

I tried one of the solution from Stack Overflow:

> Set CC,CXX before running cmake like in below steps.
>
> ```
> export CC=/usr/bin/g++
> export CXX=/usr/bin/g++
> ```

but I get below errors while running cmake

```
"cmake -DPLATFORM=x64 ../"
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/g++
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/g++ -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/g++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:
```

Comment: `/usr/bin/g++` is **C++** compiler, not **C** one. C compiler is `/usr/bin/gcc` and exactly it should be set as `CC` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For individual files you can set the language yourself independent of the file extension by setting the [`LANGUAGE` source file property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/LANGUAGE.html):

```
# compile foo.c and bar.c with the C++ compiler
set_source_files_properties(foo.c bar.c PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)
```

This results in CMake using the C++ compiler for the `.c` files regardless of the compilers used for C / C++.

---

It may be possible to achieve the same effect for the whole project by listing only C++ as language, but I haven't tested this option:

```
# top level project
project(MyProject LANGUAGES CXX)

...
```